# EF Core code first creates additional attribute on its own

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I'm practicing code first on random example, this is my code:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public string SpecializationName { get; set; }
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
    public virtual Specialization Specialization { get; set; }
}

public class Specialization
{
    public string SpecializationName { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Employee> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Employees");
        builder.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Section);
        builder.HasOne(x => x.Specialization);
    }
}

public class SpecializationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Specialization>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Specialization> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Specializations");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.SpecializationName);

        builder.Property(x => x.SpecializationName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);
    }
}
```

All works fine, except after updating migration one new attribute appear - `SpecializationName1` in `Employees` table. Additional one is FK, original is not, which is even weirder. I have absolutely no idea how to fix it because it does things almost on its own, I have never typed `SpecializationName1` in the code.

Comment: Based on [Ivan Stoevs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62393277/286934), does it work when you rename `SpecializationName` in the `Specialization` class/entity to just `Name` (so it will be `Specialization`+`Name`)? Or does it work when you rename `SpecializationName` in the `Employee` class/entity to `SpecializationSpecializationName` (so it will be `Specialization`+`SpecializationName`) to fit the format described in the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting, you seems to be hitting EF Core 3.x bug.

The property name `SpecializationName` in `Employee` doesn't seem to match any of the EF Core FK name conventions

> If the dependent entity contains a property with a name matching one of these patterns then it will be configured as the foreign key:
>
> - `<navigation property name><principal key property name>`
> - `<navigation property name>Id`
> - `<principal entity name><principal key property name>`
> - `<principal entity name>Id`

so it is discarded, but then somehow the default generated FK is the same, and since it is "reserved", EF appends suffix "1" at the end.

As usual when EF Core conventions don't work, the solution is to use explicit mapping, e.g. in `EmployeeConfiguration`

```
builder.HasOne(x => x.Specialization)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.SpecializationName);
```

Comment: This makes me hate it even more. I'm more of a SQL person, if we are talking about databases. Either way it fixes the issue. Thanks for help, if its really a glitch it saved me countless hours of googling.